# Attaching data from matrix to another

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, data-conversion

I have a problem with my data. 
Some info for you:
I have two cannals of data `Bx` - red one (Canal 1) and `By` - blue one, (Canal 3), both of them contain 266336 records. Both measurements are taken in 300 seconds. As a result of my plot I got yaxis which gives me correct unit, which is picoTesla, but xaxis gives me number of samples instead of time. Look:

```
plt.plot(Bx, label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.1, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(By, label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.1, linestyle="-")
```

[image]

About my code, I have managed to create matrix, which define time:

```
dt = float(300)/266336
Fs = 1/dt
t = [0,300,dt*1e3]
```

My data matrix looks like this:

```
a = np.amin(data.data)
Bx = data.data[0,]
By = data.data[1,]
```

I know that from those 266336 records 887,78409 take place in every second. But how to do this? How to write to python, to let him know, that every second is occupied by 887,78409 samples.

UPDATE!
Using this code:

```
N = len(Bx)
time = np.linspace(0, 300, N)
plt.plot(time, Bx, ...)
```

I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all you need to define your time is: `np.linspace(0,300,266336)`.

This divides the `[0, 300]` interval into `266336` equal 'steps'.

```
N = len(Bx)
time = np.linspace(0, 300, N)
plt.plot(time, Bx, ...)
```

[mcve]:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Bx = np.random.rand(266336)

N = len(Bx)
time = np.linspace(0, 300, N) # or 300000

plt.figure(1).clf()
plt.plot(time, Bx)
```

If this (alone) doesn't work, then I'm clueless why, because it works for me. If it does work but your script doesn't then find what else you are doing in your script that screws up your figure display...

Comment: How should I put it into code? Modify `plt.plot`? Or define new variable where `np.line....` is time

Comment: Yep, look at mine.

Comment: I doesn't work like that, because when I extend your command `np.linespace(0,300000, N)` I see whole xaxis, but not from 1 to 300, only 1 to 300000.

Comment: Well of course if you use 300000, you'll see 300000... I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Can you Look at my edited question? You cannot just force xaxis to be 300 unit long if you have 266336 records. That means that my measurements do not synchronize with time, that's why I gave you the number of samples in each second (887,78409)

Comment: Please look at my updated graph. Only 0 appear on the scale. Do you know why? Guess not. So let me explain, if you use `np.linspace` you just shorten my scale. I have 266336 data, and you put a command to python to make a scale for it which contain only 300 records, that's why nothing except 0 appear after using your command. Is that clear? So that does not resolve my problem at all.

Comment: No `np.linspace(x_min, x_max, N)` will create an array of size `N` (if it didn't it would generate an error in the `plt.plot` call) . I believe your problem is that for some weird reason your scale display is f...d up. Did you play with the figure / axis settings in any way? When I try it here with random data for Bx it just works fine as expected... See [mcve] in edit.

Comment: I have to pay you respect. I found a misspelling in my code, that's why your command did not work. My bad. And thanks for helping. Apologise for inconvenience.